# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '(controlName: string) => boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
hasError(typeofvalidator:string, controlname:string) : boolean 
{
    return this.CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup.contains[controlname].hasError(typeofvalidator);
 }
```

I'm Learning Angular, In the course video has same code but it is running in the course but I'm getting the Error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong need help please.
[image]

Comment: FYI: Angularjs is a prior version... if not ancestor and different package... than Angular. You should change the tags from Angularjs to Angular.

Comment: Re: "In the course video has same code": Are you sure? The code that you've posted doesn't make a lot of sense. I strongly suspect that you've miscopied something.

Comment: I have Attached the Picture of the code from the Course

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try replacing the square brackets `[]` after your `contains` with normal parentheses `()`? Looks like the error says you're trying to index a function.

So should maybe look more like this:

```
return this.CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup.contains(controlname).hasError(typeofvalidator);
```

After this I assume your initial error will be resolved, but there might be another one.

Comment: Getting `Property 'hasError' does not exist on type 'boolean'`

Comment: @GunasekaranS Yes that is expected, since `contains` returns a `boolean`. You have to call `hasError` on a `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, or `AbstractControl` object. I would suggest refactoring your code to look something like this:

`return this.formGroup.get('formControlName').hasError('errorType');`

Note that the formGroup in this line of code refers to a `FormGroup` object that has a `FormControl` inside of it, with the name 'formControlName' in this example.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, break up each step into several strongly typed variables.

```js
hasError(typeofvalidator:string, controlname:string) : boolean 
{
  const customerModel: {formerCustomerGroup: string} = this.CustomerModel;

  const fCG: string = customerModel.formCustomerGroup;

  return fCG.contains[controlname].hasError(typeofvalidator);
}
```

I don't know why yours doesn't work, and I'm sure that mine won't work either for whatever reasons yours doesn't work, but it will break up the problem into a spot that's very identifiable and then you can work from there.

When you've fixed it, you can change it back to the shorter version if you like, but here you've hit a snag, and it's time to go searching.

Good hunting!

Comment: Thank you ! Still searching for solution

Comment: Yes, Your's also not working either

Comment: I just realized that string.prototype.contains returns a boolean. And booleans don't have a hasError method.

Comment: @JSmart523: But this code isn't calling `contains`, it's retrieving a dynamically-specified property of `contains`. (Which seems very strange to me, but maybe it makes sense in the original code?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```js
hasError(typeofValidator: string, controlname: string): boolean {
    return this.customerModel.formCustomerGroup.controls[controlname].hasError(typeofValidator);
}
```

Solution:

Just replace `controlname` with `ControlName`.

```js
hasError(typeofValidator: string, controlName: string): boolean {
    return this.customerModel.formCustomerGroup.controls[controlName].hasError(typeofValidator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not `contains`. You should use `controls` instead try this

```
return this.NewCustomer
              .FormCustomerGroup
              .controls[ControlName]
              .hasError(TypeOfValidator);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of error. I was able to resolve the error by using get(controlName) instead of controls[controlName].
I am using Typescript 4.8.2 and Angular CLI 15.0.0

```
return this.customerModel.formCustomerGroup.get(controlName)?.hasError(typeofValidator)
```